# Java: Unsigned byte to int conversion works perfectly except for 129 (0x81)

Tags: java, string, iterator, arrays

I have a weird problem with unsigned byte to int conversion in Java.
The Hex value 0x81 (129 in decimal) always gets interpreted wrongly as 63.
Every other value works normally. Maybe this is because the bytes are stored in a string before the conversion.

```
//some string
String text=new String(bytearray);
//create an iterator to go through the bytes
byte[] bytes=text.getBytes();
List<Byte> list=new ArrayList<Byte>();
for(byte i:bytes){
list.add(i);
}
Iterator<Byte> it=list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
//bitwise AND 0xFF to remove 2's complement
int a=it.next()&0xFF;
}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

**Solution**

```
//some string, this time I use a char[] to fill it.
String text=new String(chararray);
//create an iterator to go through the bytes
char[] chars=text.toCharArray();
List<Byte> list=new ArrayList<Byte>();
for(char i:chars){
list.add((byte)i);
}
Iterator<Byte> it=list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
//bitwise AND 0xFF to remove 2's complement
int a=it.next()&0xFF;
}
```

Comment: As a note, no primitive gets stored as a String, and they definitely don't get stored as a String before conversion.

Comment: Mocking up the `bytes` array with bytes including `(byte) 129`, and outputting each `a` each loop, I get 129 outputted.  Are you sure your bytes don't include an actual 63 (0x3F), a `'?'` character?

Comment: Adding to @rgettman: `getBytes()` uses the default platform encoding to encode the Unicode characters into a byte stream. If there is any character which is not displayable in the platform default encoding, a literal `?` might be substituted. So please tell us your platform *and* your default encoding.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is exactly the problem. My default Charset is "windows-1252" and my OS is Windows 7 64Bit. 0x81 is the invalid character -127 (unsigned its 129). Therefore my new question is: How can i create a String without a Charset?

Comment: @tly: You can use `latin1` as the encoding. This gets the job done in most cases. However: Conversion from `String` (or `char`) to `byte` and back always requires an encoding. We are not in C land after all ;-)

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I found a solution. Its a bit clumsy, but it works! (See above)

Answer (score 3):

The byte data type is an `8-bit` signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of `-128` and a maximum value of `127` (inclusive).

Comment: Thats true, but the bitwise AND with 0xFF removes the complement, so the byte is treated as unsigned. By "Every other value works normally" I mean all values from 0(0x00) to 255(0xFF) expect for 129.